# Why support comparison between different data types based on (seemingly) arbitrary rules?

Tags: language-agnostic, syntax, language-design

My questions is, "Why would a language designer consider allowing comparison between different data types?". Also, does this make more sense in a functional language?

For example, in erlang one can perform the following comparisons:

```
%% Tuples are greater than numbers
999999 < {1,2}.
true

%% Lists are greater than tuples
{90000} < [1].
true

%% Atoms are greater than numbers
1 < false.
true
```

In python 2.x as well,

```
p = lambda x,y: x+y

p > (1)
True

p < (1)
False

p == (1)
False
```

Though looks like the python community decided this wasn't a good idea after all:

> objects of different types always
>   compare unequal, and are ordered
>   consistently but arbitrarily.
>   [...]
>   This unusual definition of comparison
>   was used to simplify the definition of
>   operations like sorting and the in and
>   not in operators.
>   [source](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html)

From the Python 3 release note:

> The ordering comparison operators (<,
>   <=, >=, >) raise a TypeError exception
>   when the operands don’t have a
>   meaningful natural ordering. Thus,
>   expressions like 1 < '', 0 > None or
>   len <= len are no longer valid, and
>   e.g. None < None raises TypeError
>   instead of returning False. A
>   corollary is that sorting a
>   heterogeneous list no longer makes
>   sense – all the elements must be
>   comparable to each other.
>   [source](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html)

This kind of explains why, but I was wondering if there are other reasons to allow this, particularly in functional languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In dynamic languages it makes a certain amount of sense, as it's nice to be able to sort heterogeneous lists and build heterogeneous trees.  And I think I would say that it's not so much *functional* languages where it's dubious as it is *strongly typed* languages, for obvious reasons.